# Pass Data From Two Classes In React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i have no clue how to do this,

i have two classes that have input fields one of them will be rendered

depending on the button clicked on the previous page, both of them will

render input fields. Now i want to grab the state of the one rendered and

pass it to the exported class in my view

here is my two classes

```
class DoctorInput extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    this.state = { practitionerType: '', employee : '', clinic : '' };

  }

  render() {

    return (

      <View>

        <Dropdown style={{ flex : 1, textAlign: 'center' }} inputContainerStyle={{ alignItems: 'center' }} titleTextStyle={{ textAlign: 'center' }} data={ FormData.practitionerType } onChangeText={ (dentistType) => this.setState({ practitionerType : dentistType }) } label="Dentist Type" />

        <TextField style={{ flex : 1, textAlign: 'center' }} inputContainerStyle={{ alignItems: 'center' }} titleTextStyle={{ textAlign: 'center' }} onChangeText={ (employeeNumber) => this.setState({ employee : employeeNumber }) } label="Registeration N./ Student N." />

        <TextField style={{ flex : 1, textAlign: 'center' }} inputContainerStyle={{ alignItems: 'center' }} titleTextStyle={{ textAlign: 'center' }} onChangeText={ (clinicAddress) => this.setState({ clinic : clinicAddress }) } label="Clinic Address" />

      </View>

    )

  }

}

class PatientInput extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    this.state = { history: '' };

  }

  render() {

    return (

      <View>

        <TextField style={{ flex : 1, textAlign: 'center' }} inputContainerStyle={{ alignItems: 'center' }} titleTextStyle={{ textAlign: 'center' }} onChangeText={ (history) => this.setState({ history : history }) } label="History" />

      </View>

    )

  }

}
```

on of them will be rendered depending on a value that get's passed from

previous page, and the one to be rendered is determined in a simple if

statement

```
const doctor = <DoctorInput />

const patient = <PatientInput />

let userType;

if (this.props.navigation.getParam('userType') == 'doctor') userType = doctor;

else userType = patient
```

then i simply added `{ userType }` to render the one i need,

now the problem is i have absolutely no clue how to grab the state of

the rendered inputs to the main class submit function

here is my submit function

```
signUp = async () => {

await this.setState({ userType : this.props.navigation.getParam('userType') });

let user = this.state;

console.log(user);

}
```

how may i grab the values of either DoctorInput or PatientInput fields ?

Comment: Are you using redux or mobx for state mangement? Might be worth looking into

Comment: @TallPaul Do you really think this calls for the introduction of redux?

Comment: I agree @1252748, the burden of adding a state management tool is probably too much for this case. I believe that it would be a viable solution (it's actually how form packages work in most cases) but the decision shouldn't be solely based on the need for children inputs to update parent state when options like callback's and formik are available

Comment: @1252748 not saying that this is the sole reason to add it. I just have found that apps start simple and run into small issues like this consistently that could be solved by sharing state between screens. Another alternative is storing it in localstate but it is not my project and only asking for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a function to the parent that takes a value and sets local state.

```
handleInput(theInputValue){ 
 this.setState({inputValue: theInputValue}) 
}
```

you can add this function to children components

```
const doctor = <DoctorInput callback={this.handleInput} />

const patient = <PatientInput callback={this.handleInput} />
```

from within your children components, you can access the value of your input's on change and update the local state of the parent.

```
    <TextField onChangeText={e=>this.props.callback(e.val)}/>
```

I, however, do not advise this solution as this will become overly complicated and burden your code base. If you decide to take this route, however, I would make the function set state as an object of key/values for better access from the parent.

Have you seen Formik? https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik might lessen your burden of work.